# TextToSpeech.stop() is not working

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am calling text to speech speak() continously in `onUteranceComplete()` method, when an event occurs. The speak method is working fine and it is continously speaking the text but I am facing a weird problem in this code. When the event finishes, I call `textToSpeech.stop()` method, but the speak method keeps speaking and it seems like stop() isn't working at all. I guess the problem is occuring because of calling speak() continously in onUteranceCOmplete().

What do you experts think, what is the cause of this problem?

```
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text to speech created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                tts.setPitch(1.2f);
                tts.setSpeechRate(1.0f);

                tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        tts.speak("hello world", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, hash);

                    }
                });
            }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
       ....
       x = tts.speak("hello world", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, hash);
   }
```

Regards

Comment: Experts not needed.. If you tell something to stop and then start again... what do you think is going to happen? Stop just stops what currently is being spoken. If you call speak again its going to speak no matter how many times you've called stop

Comment: so can you give me an idea on how to stop it then, cuz I don't want to get rid of onUteranceComplete listener

Comment: Post your relevant codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a class member flag

```
private boolean mShouldSpeak = true;
```

and then check the flag in onUtteranceCompleted

```
tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (mShouldSpeak) 
                    {
                        tts.speak("hello world", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, hash);
                    }

                }
            });
```

When the event finished just set `mShouldSpeak to false`